# Как реабилитироваться после хвальбы в комментариях вместо поставленной галочки и есть ли способы намека на это?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ответы, правила

Мне плохо, мозговая активность на исходе. Людям же пишут, **не оставляйте комментарии со "Спасибо, помогло"**, а ставьте галачку, но нет блин. Есть ли какой то способ **незаметно** намекнуть человеку что он делает не правильно???

P.S. Я понимаю что галочка это дело пользователя, но это не какая то соц.сеть с комментариями

Comment: теги у данного вопроса странные (дизайн?). По сути: а почему это нужно делать незаметно? В чем проблема напрямую сказать что-то типа "Если данный ответ вам помог, то его можно отметить галочкой как верный"?

Comment: Возможно её просто не замечают

Comment: ок. если галочку не замечают или о ней не знают - зачем об этом намекать, особенно незаметно? Прямо и уважительно сказать, оставив в формулировке человеку свободу действия.

Comment: Если намекать *незаметно*, то этого не заметят ;-) // А по делу - не придавайте галкам такого большого внимания. ТС не всегда обладает полнотой знаний даже чтобы определить правильность ответа (иначе он бы не задавал вопроса), а уж тем более верно выбрать лучший правильный ответ из нескольких. Так что ориентируйтесь в первую очередь на голоса, а не на галки )

Comment: @Kromster, но ответ на первом месте фиксирует именно галочка.

Comment: @Qwertiy к сожалению да. ИМХО это известная недоработка SE :-)

Comment: ИМХО, вообще лучше не писать про галочки в ответе - это выглядит довольно странно (особенно когда [ответ не отвечает на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1301040/1365)). Если автор отметится в комментарии к ответу, я обычно напоминаю про галку, а так везде писать про галки довольно бессмысленно и неестественно. Галки вообще не главное. Если ответ хороший, на него прилетит несколько плюсов, а галка - это так, бонус.